# Calling stored procedure ignoring output parameters

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to call MySql procedure as a plain text. Procedure has output parameter.
I'm not interested in returned data. 
What do I need to pass as output parameter to ignore it?

PS:

*I know that using of SqlParameters is good and safe, but it is not my case.*

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SqlConnection mySqlConnection = ConnectDB();
SqlCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
mySqlCommand.CommandText =
   @" 
      SQL QUERY HERE
   ";
mySqlConnection.Open();
mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
mySqlConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Not exact. I need to call "MyStoredProcedure @outputParam"